# Which linux server distrabution best to run lamp server for production enviroment?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat, lamp

Which Linux server distribution the best to run lamp server for production environment?
1. sharing hosting
2. virtual hosting
3. dedicated hosting
(Ubuntu server, redhat,....)
Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whichever you're most comfortable with, as long as it's a serious distribution with good track record for security updates. For servers, long support time tends to be nice as well.

I'd say RHEL (or clones thereof such as CentOS), SLES, Ubuntu LTS, and Debian are all good choices.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Ubuntu server mainly for the vast amount of support you can receive via Ubuntu forums. I've solved many a problem there. However, if this is a production server you will most likely want to purchase a proper support package... but free advice never hurt.

Comment: Ubuntu have also enterprise support

Answer (score 1):

Most of the servers run on CentOS Linux (clone of RedHat Linux). Ubuntu/Debian is also good choice. Depends.. on which platform you are good at. All are good.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this answer is: it depends :) In your place, I'd choose the one I was most comfortable with. Every distro has its pros and cons. I've experience with a few Linux distros (RedHat, Debian, CentOS, Ubuntu, Caixa Mágica) and my favorite one is Debian.

I think that it's the most "clean" Linux distro and that it has the best packaging system in the world. On the other side, some commercial software doesn't offer support to Debian. But Debian is the distro that I'm most comfortable with and it suits all my needs :) If you need commercial support, I'd recommend RedHat.

So, choose the one that you're more comfortable with and the one that suits all your needs!